# AWS STS assumeRole- do I have to provide access and secret keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts

I am using Amazon Javascript SDK.

I am trying to understand the AWS STS api for getting the temporary credentials to access the S3. But what I found out is that if I am providing the access and secret keys then only it os giving me session token. Otherwise it throwing an error "Missing credentials in config".

Is this how STS works? I dont want to reveal keys in javascript.

Comment: The idea is usually to do this on the server before handing the temporary credentials to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. To create a set of temporary credentials with the [Security Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), you must authenticate to AWS so that it can verify that you have the correct permissions to generate these credentials.

The steps are typically:

1. The user authenticates with your application or a 3rd-party service (eg Facebook)
2. Your application generates temporary credentials using STS (eg via the [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) API call). You must have valid AWS credentials to make this call.
3. You send the credentials to the remote application
4. The remote application uses the credentials to access AWS services

There are [numerous AWS re:Invent videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=reinvent+iam+federation&search=Search) that can explain this federation process.

Comment: Do you have code for generating signature for STS callout?